# Getting UIResponder touches

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Without subclassing a UIResponder class(e.g. UIView) and overriding its touchesBegan:withEvent: method, is it possible to get informed of touch events of a UIResponder class?

This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843717/iphone-custom-class-object-in-responder-chain).

Comment: Why do you want to do that, after all if a user is clicking on the screen some view must be there so you can always know...

Comment: of course there is always a view on the screen. but in this case, the view at the top of the screen is a framework class that I can't track touch events without subclassing it. Even if I subclass it I can't do what I want, because responder of this framework UIView class is another view inside it, that's not documented in the api. I think Meltemi's suggestion about UIApplication may help me. waiting for an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat confusing...'without subclassing UIResponder...can you get informed of touch events of UIResponder?'  Are you asking if you can add touchesBegan/Moved/Ended/Cancelled events to *any* NSObject?!?  I'm not comfortable enough with the framework yet to know for sure if those methods would be called if they were implemented as a category on or subclass of NSObject?!?

But, regardless of what you're doing, the top (end) of the responder chain is UIApplication (also a subclass of UIResponder) and if you have an iPhone app then you have a singleton of UIApplication which you can query for touch events...

Comment: Thanks, UIApplication may help me. I want to inform one of my UIView classes when the user touches down the screen. How can I make use of UIApplication to do that?

Comment: ok. I think I need to subclass it. Thanks, your answer helped me